# A folder randomly appeared in my Chromebook

Tags: file, google-drive-api, chromebook

Okay, so, I fell asleep a while ago and I've just woken up.

I downloaded this bootleg Amy Winehouse album titled 'The Other Side of Amy Winehouse (not streamable for those of you wondering why I downloaded it)

When I opened my files, I noticed that there was a folder titled 'Recovered Files from Google Drive' (I use an Acer Chromebook). It had the files (the `.mp3` files and the Album Art) but it also had these `.com` files. They were all renamed though. the mp3 files were called 'audio' followed by some numbers, image followed by numbers, then there were the com files that were titled `file------`.

When I open them, it's all text, mainly just ' , and ., with some numbers and stuff. Then there were there text things that were question marks in a diamond outline and some red dots.

Basically, I don't know where this was all coming from. Anyone got any help?

Comment: Based on your description it sounds like a binary executable file https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_file. Luckily you're not using windows. It could be a malicious software bundled with pirated music.

Answer (score 0):

It is created when something goes wrong in a google drive sync. You do not have to worry about it if you did not lose any real data. From what I've gotten from looking it up, there is nothing wrong on your side, any problem would be with Google's side, you should be able to delete the folder.

Source:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=848128#c3